# Установить значение в зависимости от строки DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть 2 типа складов складов столица и региональные.
Необходимо раскидать города в разные склады: Москву и питер в "MSKSPB", другие в "regions"
Написал следующую формулу

```
clients['Склад'] = \
    np.where(clients['Город'].map(lambda x: str(x)) == 'Москва', "MSKSPB", "Reg")
```

Как добавить в формулу еще и Питер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cities = ['Москва','Санкт-Петербург']
clients['Склад'] = np.where(clients['Город'].isin(cities), 'MSKSPB', 'Reg')
```